# Passing options by variables in bash does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I encountered a very strange behavior when running below command, let me explain the issue:

Consider this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x /ignore_dir_1/\*
```

It compresses the whole `www` folder recursively and **excludes** `ignore_dir_1` which is perfectly fine. 

Now, write that script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/\*"
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x $Exclude
```

It runs without error but **does not exclude** `ignore_dir_1`.

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

**- Disclaimer:**

I have already tried the following alternatives:
`Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/*"`
`Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/***"`

**Update:**
Thanks to @pLumo, the problem solved by putting variable inside quotation like:

```
#!/bin/bash
Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/*"
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x "$Exclude"
```

Now, the problem is if `Exclude` variable contain **multiple folders**, it does not work, I mean this:

```
#!/bin/bash
Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/* /ignore_dir_2/*"
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x "$Exclude"
```

I even tried `"${Exclude}"` but no result.

Comment: Always quote your variables --> `-x "$Exclude"`, then your first alternative should work just fine.

Comment: It worked! Can you please write your comment as an answer and also describe the reason? I would appreciate that.

Comment: That's already very well documented and if you had done what the bash tag you included tells you to do (`For shell scripts with errors/syntax errors, please check them with the shellcheck program (or in the web shellcheck server at https://shellcheck.net) before posting here.`) that tool would have told you about the issue and provided a link to documentation about it.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that, I will promise to read documentations carefully before posting. Thanks.

Comment: @pLumo Would you please read my updated question? I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Change each `zip` command to `echo zip` and review the result when you run the script. You'll (hopefully) see why the command is failing to do what you want. (Hint: double-quote your variables when you use them.)

Comment: you can also write a file of excluded patterns and pass that file to `zip`. `zip ... -x @excludes.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write ...

```bash
Exclude="/ignore_dir_1/* /ignore_dir_2/*"
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x "$Exclude"
```

, `zip` receives  `$Exclude` as a single argument, and considers the space between the files as part of the path.

---

To pass multiple arguments to your command, you need to use an `array`.

```bash
Exclude=("/ignore_dir_1/*" "/ignore_dir_2/*")
zip -r /var/backup.zip /var/www -x "${Exclude[@]}"
```

This makes sure that the items are individually expanded and passed as arguments to your command.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

*ninja'd by pLumo :-P*

---

I suggest that you use an array,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "directory tree ---------------------------------------------------"

find

echo "without exclusions -----------------------------------------------"

echo zip -sf -r backup.zip .
     zip -sf -r backup.zip .

echo "with exclusions --------------------------------------------------"

declare -a Exclude=(ignore_dir_1/\* ignore_dir_2/\*)

echo zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x ${Exclude[@]}
     zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x ${Exclude[@]}

echo 'double quoted ${Exclude[@]} --------------------------------------'


echo zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x "${Exclude[@]}"
     zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x "${Exclude[@]}"
```

Result with a directory tree shown before the 'dry runs',

```
$ ./script 
directory tree ---------------------------------------------------
.
./dir_0
./dir_0/file-1
./dir_0/file-2
./ignore_dir_1
./ignore_dir_1/file-11
./ignore_dir_1/file-12
./ignore_dir_2
./ignore_dir_2/file name with spaces
./ignore_dir_2/file-22
./ignore_dir_2/file-21
./script
without exclusions -----------------------------------------------
zip -sf -r backup.zip .
Would Add/Update:
  dir_0/
  dir_0/file-1
  dir_0/file-2
  ignore_dir_1/
  ignore_dir_1/file-11
  ignore_dir_1/file-12
  ignore_dir_2/
  ignore_dir_2/file name with spaces
  ignore_dir_2/file-22
  ignore_dir_2/file-21
  script
Total 11 entries (621 bytes)
with exclusions --------------------------------------------------
zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x ignore_dir_1/file-11 ignore_dir_1/file-12 ignore_dir_2/file-21 ignore_dir_2/file-22 ignore_dir_2/file name with spaces
Would Add/Update:
  dir_0/
  dir_0/file-1
  dir_0/file-2
  ignore_dir_1/
  ignore_dir_2/
  script
Total 6 entries (621 bytes)
double quoted ${Exclude[@]} --------------------------------------
zip -sf -r backup.zip . -x ignore_dir_1/* ignore_dir_2/*
Would Add/Update:
  dir_0/
  dir_0/file-1
  dir_0/file-2
  script
Total 4 entries (621 bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked very well. :)

Comment: @nima1024, I'm glad I could help you solve this problem :-)